# jcarousel horizontal slider with two rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have downloaded jcarousel slider but I want two rows to appear and on clicking on next or previous both rows should move simultaneously, i do not know the concepts of javascript and jquery so please tell me the steps to be taken.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mean you need 2 sliders. if you click on 1st slider's next / prev arrow, than both carousal should be effected. is that so?

If yes, then you have to try carousal's inbuilt function for customization.

1. add 2 carousal slider in your code
2. hide carousal slider arrow for 2nd slider
3. now do custumization for your 1st slider arrows. i.e. trigger 2nd
   slider whenever 1st slider is triggered. you can try to put your
   code inside carousal function:

   $('.jcarousel').on('jcarousel:scroll', function(event, carousel, target, animate) {
       // "this" refers to the root element
       // "carousel" is the jCarousel instance
       // "target" is the target argument passed to the `scroll` method
       // "animate" is the animate argument passed to the `scroll` method
       //      indicating whether jCarousel was requested to do an animation
   });

you can find various customized function from here: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to show in the second row?

Is it some info of the current image like description or the count e.g. **2** of **7** or one more set of images.

If it is info(description) you can create a div after your jCarousel container and change the content of the div on `next` and `previous` button click callback function.

Post some code to get a clear picture